# Use Desktop Screen to Show MetroDialog Message in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF, I am trying to create a MetroDialog Message as I used the code below,

```
public async Task<MessageDialogResult> ShowMessage(string message, MessageDialogStyle dialogStyle, string title)
    {
        var metroWindow = (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);

        metroWindow.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented;

        return await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync(
            title, message, dialogStyle, metroWindow.MetroDialogOptions);
    }
```

This code works perfectly in `MetroWindows`, But what I really wanted is to use the Desktop Screen and show this Message widely. Is there a possible way to do that?

Thank you and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `ShowMessageAsync` is an extension method for the `MetroWindow` class so I am afraid you can't call it or use it on any other type of window. It works in a `MetroWindow` only.

Comment: So this means that I cannot use this in Desktop Screen Sir?

Comment: @BanTot: Yes, exactly. You can only call and use `ShowMessageAsync` on a `MetroWindow`.

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you!